# How can navigate the menu using the two buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/hfv7xmo6/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-project">
    <div class="menu">MENU1</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU2</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU3</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU3</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU4</div>
</div>
<div class="content-project">
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU1</div>
    <div class="c1">
        <button class="prev">prev</button>
        <button class="next">next</button>
        CONTENT FOR MENU2
    </div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENczxczU3</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENqqU3</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $c1s = $('.content-project .c1');
    $c1s.first().show();

    $('.container-project').on('click', '.menu', function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $c1s.hide();
        $c1s.eq(index).show();
    });

      $('.prev').click(function(){
                 //code to navigate to the prev menu
      });

       $('.next').click(function(){
                  //code to navigate to the next menu
      });
});
```

What I want is that when the user clicks the "next" button to navigate to the next menu and when you click on the "prev" to navigate to the previous menu.

I do not realize how we should think about this and I need some ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please define what next menu, and previous menu is, you have a menu tree. is it the next branch, or the next node?

Comment: What you need on next and previous click? It is unclear what you say.

Comment: For example, if the user presses the "next" button to display "content for menu 3" and if the user presse the "prev" button to display "content for menu 1".

Comment: Now you understand? It is probably something simple but I did not realize how to do

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $c1s = $('.content-project .c1');
    $c1s.first().addClass('active').show();

    $('.container-project').on('click', '.menu', function () {
        var $cur = $('.content-project .c1.active');
        var index = $(this).index();
        $cur.removeClass('active').hide();
        $c1s.eq(index).addClass('active').show();
    });
    $('.prev').click(function(){
        var $cur = $('.content-project .c1.active');
        var index = $cur.index();
        if(index > 0){ // if its not 1st 
            $cur.removeClass('active').hide();
            $c1s.eq(index - 1).addClass('active').show();
        }
      });

       $('.next').click(function(){        
        var $cur = $('.content-project .c1.active');
        var index = $cur.index();
        if(index < $c1s.length){ // if its not last 
            $cur.removeClass('active').hide();
            $c1s.eq(index + 1).addClass('active').show();
        }
      });
});
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish1bhagat/hfv7xmo6/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Put your index variable (defaults to 0) outside of the elements click method, assign it value of current menu clicked. Then on previous button click, subtract 1 from current index and show that element and in next button, add 1 to current index and show that element.

In both methods, first hide the current index element.

**HTML (Update):**

```
<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
    $c1s.eq(index).hide();
    $c1s.eq(index - 1).show();
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    $c1s.eq(index).hide();
    $c1s.eq(index + 1).show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/hfv7xmo6/4/)

Comment: @Cristi, Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what u want would be propably to apply numbers / indexes to your menus. For example:

```
<div class="content-project">
    <div class="c1" id="1">CONTENT FOR MENU1</div>
    <div class="c1" id="2">
        <button class="prev">prev</button>
        <button class="next">next</button>
        CONTENT FOR MENU2
    </div>
    <div class="c1" id="3">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
    <div class="c1" id="4">CONTENT FOR MENczxczU3</div>
    <div class="c1" id="5">CONTENT FOR MENqqU3</div>
</div>
```

Then in prev/next click you can just look for the menu which is shown in this moment, get the "id" of this div. Then in prev function just hide it and show menu which have id-1, in next function id+1. Maybe there are better ways for that, but this is the easiest way for sure.